# Issue with code connected to button in access form showing runtime error 2471

Tags: vba, ms-access

when i click on a button that was set up in a form   i receive  this error

> Run-time error '2471.: the expression you entered as a query parameter
>   produced this error:"MW_client.CIRTS_Client_ID

```
'MedWaiver ALL Open Form button
Private Sub Command_MW_All_Open_Form_Click()

    ' clear old fields used by other buttons
    globalClientLastName = ""
    globalClientReferID = ""
    globalClientCIRTSID = ""
    globalClientSSN = ""
    globalStartDate = Null
    globalEndDate = Null

    ' Clear the other Query Types
    globalQueryMyOpenTriageClients = False
    globalQueryMyOpenEligibilityClients = False
    globalQueryStartEndDates = False
    globalQueryClientLastName = False
    globalQueryClientReferID = False
    globalQueryClientCIRTSID = False
    globalQueryClientSSN = False
    globalQueryStaff = False
    globalQueryAddClients = False
    globalQueryCompleted = False
    globalQueryDelete = False


    ' set the query type to ALL Open Clients
    globalQueryAllOpen = True

    ' Check to see how many records match
    If DCount("*", "MedWaiver LIST - Query") > 0 Then  - here is the issue 
    ' open the form for MedWaiver Clients
        DoCmd.OpenForm "MedWaiver Release FORM"
    Else
        MsgBox "No records matched your OPEN search"
    End If

    ' open the form for MedWaiver Clients
    ' DoCmd.OpenForm "MedWaiver Release FORM"

End Sub
```

Comment: That "error" is buried in the query "MedWaiver LIST - Query".

Comment: No errors come up when i run that query

Comment: Perhaps you need the full syntax: `DCount("*", "[MedWaiver LIST - Query]")`.

Comment: I tested without the [ ] for query name and it works. Edit question to post entire SQL statement. Is that really the entire error message?

Comment: Apparently you're using a parameter in your query. You'll have to add that parameter to your DCount.